# SQL. Сделать проверку с EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

мне нужно регистрировать пользователь в БД и для этого я должен проверить не существует ли такого логина (номера телефона) уже в базе и если да то зарегистрировать.

Пример:

```
INSERT INTO Client (Name, Last_Name, Address, City, Phone, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '123456789', 'Norway');
```

Все мои логины (номера телефонов) и пароли находяться в представлении Users
Как именно мне сделать проверку с Exists.

Проблему решил таким условием

```
if exists(select log from login_phone where log = phone)
then raise exception 'Уже существует такой телефон. В регистрации отказано';
```

Answer (score 0):

По-хорошему, проверки такого рода возможны только для получения человеческих сообщений об ошибке на клиенте.
В реальности же полагаться на `exists` нельзя, потому как нет никаких гарантий, что все записи будут вставляться через метод API, который вы описываете.
Специально для таких ситуаций SQL предлагает вам создавать [ограничения уникальности (unique constraints)](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/11/ddl-constraints#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS), описав которые, вы можете быть уверены в том, что в таблице точно всё будет хорошо:

```sql
-- на этапе создания таблицы
CREATE TABLE Client (
    Phone bigint UNIQUE,
);

-- для уже созданной таблицы
ALTER TABLE Client ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (Phone);
```

В случае с номером телефона вам можно так же задуматься о создании [уникального индекса](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/11/sql-createindex), это, кроме вышеописанного, позволит БД быстрее выполнять запросы, если выборка будет вестись по этому полю.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Phone_idx ON Client(Phone);
```

Comment: А, если у меня 3 таблицы с номерами телефонами (клиенты,сотрудники и админ). Как мне для них всех проверять уникальность телефона ? Или можно через уникальный индекс это как-то сделать ?

Comment: @JuniorLittle я не видел ТЗ, но в таких случаях обычно не принято иметь отдельные таблицы, так как нет гарантий, что админ не станет клиентом/сотрудником (и т.п.). К тому же, с разными таблицами будет сложнее реализовать авторизацию. Можно так:

- завести таблицу `users` и таблицы `admins`, `clients`, `employees`, которые имели бы поле `user_id`, ссылающееся через [foreign key](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/11/ddl-constraints#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) на `id` таблицы `users`

- или использовать одну таблицу `users` с признаками `is_admin`/`is_emploee`, если структура плюс-минус похожая

Comment: У меня структура `клиент` `сотрудник`  - 2 мои таблицы и у всех есть внешний ключ `id_user`. Таблица `users` где написано  `id_user и название` (в названии имею введу кто: клиент или сотрудник) и все номера телефонов и паролей находяться отдельно в представлении к которому я обращаюсь и вхожу в аккаунт

Comment: Может мне как-то представление проверять ? Не сущли там номера....

Comment: @JuniorLittle я бы настоятельно рекомендовал вам не выносить проверки из БД. Проверки представления не дают никаких гарантий целостности БД, в то время как правильно настроенные ограничения - дают.

Хороший вариант - это иметь таблицу `users` (с номерами телефонов, хэшами+солями паролей и, возможно, другой общей информацией) и отдельные таблицы для разных сущностей с внешними ключами на `users.id`. Такой вариант лишает огромного количество проблем, в том числе связанных с масштабируемостью.

Однако, в итоге, конечно, решать вам.

Comment: Я решил проблему, хотя не такой и хороший вариант. Я перед внесение буду проверять существует ли в моем представлении уже такой телефон и если да то запрещяю, а если нету то разрешаю делать дальше